# How to redirect custom post type posts to one url?

Tags: wordpress, redirect, custom-post-type

I have a custom post type "products". I would like to redirect all posts from "products" to one url ex: http://example.com/page1 using htaccess.

For example:
http://example.com/products/post1, http://example.com/products/post2 and http://example.com/products/post3 to be on link click redirected to one page http://example.com/page1

I cant find this topic anywhere. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^products/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I cant get this to work, where to add destination page url?

Comment: Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^products/(.*)$ /page1 [R=301,L]

Comment: It gets the string that is in between the parentheses, refers to it with $1 and places it behind /. In other words it places the string that is between the parentheses after /, so /products/car will redirect to /car.

Answer (score 0):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?([^/d]+)/?$ products/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Try out this code and report feedback please
If the first one doesn't work try out the second

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?/([^/d]+)/?$ products/$1 [L,QSA]
```

I cannot test the code at the moment i'm not sure if you need to add the / in between ^/? and ([^/d]+)/?$.